# Vaildation error using &amp;

Tags: xml

I have a navigation menu which is populated using XML for structure. I have added `&amp;` which is the proper what to include & in XML but it is throwing an error. I have even tried escaping it as `"&amp;"` as the Validation suggests but then it gives me 4 other errors which I know don't exist because if I remove the & all together I get no errors. Another strange thing is it is parsing it correctly.

Is this correct or am I missing something and not doing it right?

Here is what the line looks like that I am using it in.

```
<item caption="Frost &amp; Freeze Outlooks" link="wxffoutlook.php"/>
```

Here is the link to the validation error.

[VALIDATION MARKUP](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.mesquiteweather.net/wxffoutlook.php&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&verbose=1&st=1&user-agent=W3C_Validator/1.3%20http://validator.w3.org/services)

Comment: Is your tag example from your XML or the page you are integrating it in?

Comment: The error you linked to and the code you post don't match, thats bad. Additionaly plaese check that your xml isn't processed before validation - cause the ampersand isn't escaped (`&amp;`) when you are validating, as the error message clearly shows.

Comment: You have to write `&amp;` in HTML as well (if & is _not_ meant to start an entity notation). So if you want to get `&amp;` _from_ your XML, try to "double-encode" it in there: `&amp;amp;`

Comment: Try using `&#038;` instead of `&amp;`.

Comment: OK, added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write `&amp;` in HTML as well (if & is not meant to start an entity notation).

So if you want to get `&amp;` from your XML, "double-encode" it in there: `&amp;amp;`